# Java regex - get line number from matching text

Tags: java, regex

It's based from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758621/java-get-text-from-jtextarea-by-number-line).

For my case I want to get number of line from regex pattern. E.g :

```
name : andy
birth : jakarta, 1 jan 1990
number id : 01011990 01
age : 26
study : Informatics engineering
```

I want to get number of line from text that match of number `[0-9]+`. I wish output like this :

```
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

Comment: Could you specify your question? Where are the lines you talking about? And why you would use RegEx?

Comment: lines that contain number (decimal). Are u have best way ?

Comment: If you want to extract all lines containing numbers see answers below.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729354/on-which-line-number-was-the-regex-match-found

Answer (score 5):

This will do it for you. I modified the regular expression to `".*[0-9].*"`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

class RegExLine 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new RegExLine().run();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        String fileName = "C:\\Path\\to\\input\\file.txt";
        AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) 
        {
            stream.forEach(s -> 
            {
                atomicInteger.getAndIncrement();
                if(Pattern.matches(".*[0-9].*", s))
                {
                    System.out.println("line "+ atomicInteger);
                }
            });
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Small, simple - has to be Java 8 ;=) Care using the right JDK @newbie

Comment: @newbie can you please accept my answer, or clarify your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Scanner` to iterate all lines of your input. And use `Matcher` Object to check for RegEx Pattern.

```
String s = "name : andy\n" +
           "birth : jakarta, 1 jan 1990\n" +
           "number id : 01011990 01\n" + 
           "age : 26\n" +
           "study : Informatics engineering";

Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
int lineNr = 1;
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(".*[0-9].*").matcher(line);
    if(m.matches()){
        System.out.println("line " + lineNr);
    }
    lineNr++;
}
```

Comment: how to not matching line by line ? it will get long time if my text is very lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply have the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int i = 1;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*[0-9]+.*");
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("..."))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (pattern.matcher(line).matches()) {
                System.out.println("line " + i);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

This code simply opens a [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) to a given file path and iterates over each line in it (until [`readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) returns `null`, indicating the end of the file). If the line matches the pattern `".*[0-9]+.*"`, meaning the line contains at least a digit, the line number is printed.

Comment: how to not matching line by line ? it will get long time if i have tons of text.

Comment: @newbie You want to print the line number so you will have to go through each line, you can't know in advance if a line matches or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use Matcher Object to check for RegEx Pattern.

```
    public static void main( String[] args )
        {
            String s = "name : andy\n" + "birth : jakarta, 1 jan 1990\n" + "number id : 01011990 01\n" + "age : 26\n"
                    + "study : Informatics engineering";
            try
            {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( ".*[0-9].*" );
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( s );
                int line = 1;
                while ( matcher.find() )
                {
                    line++;
                    System.out.println( "line :" + line );
                }
            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This can lead to wrong results. If some line does match you're not incresing line counter which is wrong. To be able to use this solution, you must be sure that every line has exactly one match